# Edit ArcGIS Feature Service with QGIS

Tags: qgis, editing, rest, feature-service

When I add an ArcGIS feature service in QGIS, the Digitizing Tools become disabled.

Is there any way to edit data from ArcGIS Rest Services (Feature Services from ArcGIS Server 10.5.1 like WFS services) with QGIS 2.18.20 ?

Comment: perhaps editing requires a username and password upon connection?

Answer (score 4):

Editing ArcGIS Feature Service layers is not possible in any current QGIS version (as of August 2018).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Can you mention the reasons why this is not possible?

Comment: There's no technical reason why not, it's just that no one has developed or sponsored it yet

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's possible according to this: https://north-road.com/2022/11/24/qgis-3-28-improvements-for-working-with-esri-formats-and-services/