# Adding features to ArcGIS Feature Service in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, feature-service, arcgis-collector

I use Collector for ArcGIS to collect data in the field, and I'd like to have collaborators w/o ESRI logins be able to contribute data to my project GIS using QField. I was hoping it would be as simple as adding the ArcGIS Feature Server url in QGIS; but after doing that, I can only view existing features in the feature service, not add new features (Add Point Feature is greyed out).

Any ideas on if it is possible to add new features to ArcGIS feature service using QField as a client instead of Collector?

Comment: It seems unlikely that QGIS has this ability, but I'm interested to see if anyone has any ideas. You could make a feature request and try to find someone to develop it, but that would take a while (at least months, possibly a year), and it might turn out to violate some ESRI copyright or terms of service. Another route you could take is to find another format they can collect the data in, then find an automated way on your end to integrate the data into the feature service.

Comment: Actually this kind of change could be implemented in qgis fairly easily, if finances are available to sponsor the development time. There's no legal or copyright reasons preventing it. BUT - you may have issues with user licenses, as only level 2 users can edit (non public) feature services. That restriction applies regardless of the actual tool used to edit. (You could possibly share user logons to avoid this, but that DEFINITELY violates your ESRI license agreement)

Comment: The user licence limitations are something I'll need to look in to more. ESRI provides sample code of ArcGIS Runtime SDK code to develop mobile apps for field data collection. But maybe use of those apps also fall under license agreements, since they rely on an ArcGIS feature service. Will check with our license admin. Thx.

Comment: related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/292184/edit-arcgis-feature-service-with-qgis (possible but no qgis funds/sponsor to implement)